# Is there a universal network driver for all motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers

I have an [ECS GeForce6100PM-M2 v.30 motherboard](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=988) which I bought 2<sup>nd</sup> hand. The vendor did not provide any drivers as he said it was plug and play. I downloaded the drivers on the main website of ECS and looked for the model of my motherboard and chose the correct OS. (Windows 7 64bit).

I downloaded all drivers except BIOS updates and installed them, restarted and reconnected my Ethernet cable at the back, but still no access to the Internet?

I tried the troubleshoot action in Windows and it says it has some driver problems.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with 'there is still no internet'. Does the NIC get recognised (if not it is indeed a driver problem), or it it recognized just fine but is it not yet configured for your LAN? etc etc.

Comment: Also, as to regards to the title of your question (and ignoring everything in the body): No, there is no single universal driver for **all** motherboards. There are drivers for a whole range of devices, but there is nothing which works with everything ever produced.

Comment: yes the nic is recognized but when i connect it to the ethernet port still no internet. and when I troubleshoot problem in windows it says it is a problem with the drivers. I downloaded all drivers on their website on my mobo and correct OS.

Comment: Please go to [start] [run] and start `demmgmt.msc`. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/vNH5u.png). Then report the state of the NIC in your post. That one should show up fine (e.g. no yellow exclamation mark).

Next start a shell ([start] [run] `cmd`) and run `ipconfig` or `ipconfig /all`.  Copy that information (right click in cmd, select copy and then select with the mouse). Add that the the post using the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/820727/edit) link.  You might want to put that between a `<pre>` and a `</pre>` or add four spaces in front of every line.

Comment: (A universal network driver! wouldn't that be heaven **dreams** - and maybe graphics drivers too)

Answer (score -1):

Hennes is correct - there is no one driver for every single motherboard.

As for your particular driver, you can try a vendor search using [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com). You can find your driver details in Device Manager (right-click on device > Properties).

I did this for my server because the hardware is very old and it worked.